# Htaccess change php extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How I can show on browser url my php file without .php extension
SO:

instead `home.php` , just `home`

How to do that with .htaccess, what I need to write in this file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cleaner URLs with .htaccess files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/cleaner-urls-with-htaccess-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: how will looks like the .htaccess file, just that ?

Comment: Yes just this line `Options +MultiViews` in .htaccess will be enough.

Comment: ok, but now when I add link home.php this links show on browser ... so I need to change all my links, and I have many of them, is there a way to stay old links (home.php) and when I click to show just "home" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is risky rule and will cause rewrite loop.